# How to get started on creating choropleth map

Tags: r, heatmap, tigris

The task at hand is mapping the empprevyearpct value to a county map. The sample data is below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)

countyname <- c("Carson City","Churchill County","Clark County","Douglas County","Elko County","Esmeralda County","Eureka County","Humboldt County","Lander County","Lincoln County","Lyon County","Mineral County","Nye County","Pershing County","Storey County","Washoe County","White Pine County")

prevyearpct <- c(.545,.541,.539,.401,.301,.201,.101,.001,.664,.604,.704,.123,.129,.130,.085,.015,.099)

data2 <- data.frame(countyname, prevyearpct)
```

Here is the code that I use from Tigris to get the shape file.

```
NV_counties <- counties(32)
```

I do not need the work done for me. If I was to map the prevyearpct values on to the counties, where would I start? Do I need to append the data so that the NV_Counties and data2 are one consolidated item? I have read quite a few articles/tutorials but nothing that uses tigris.

Comment: This would be a choropleth map, not a heat map. The latter would have to be gridded data.  This is a very common mistake, but a mistake it remains :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`geo_join()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tigris/versions/1.0/topics/geo_join) to join the two datasets together. After that, you can use `geom_sf()` to map it out ([this guide](https://r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html) may help).